# How to calculate intersections of timeranges?

Tags: c#, .net

I have got a text file that all lines like:

> 8:30 8:50 1
>
> ..........
>
> 20:30 20:35 151

Every line is a new user connection with it's time period in In-net.

The goal is to find periods of time where the quantity reaches the maximum.
So, maybe someone knows algorithm that can help me with this task(multiple intersections)? Find this task non-trivial for me(because i am new in programming), i have some ideas but i find them awful, that's why maybe i should start with mathematical algorithms to make the best way to achieve my goal.

Comment: [What have you tried so far that isn't working](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Have you ever tried anything? Just write your code here and ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For beginning we have to make some assumptions.

1. Assume you are looking for the shortest period with maximum connections.
2. Assume every line represents one connection. It's not clear from our
   question what are the integer numbers after start and end times on
   every line. So I ignore it.
3. The lines are given in order of increasing period start time.
4. We are free to choose any local maximum as the answer in case we got several periods with the same number of simultaneous connections.

The first stage of the solution is parsing. Given a sequence of lines we get the sequence of pairs of [System.DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y(v=vs.110).aspx) – a pair for each period in  order.

```
static Tuple<DateTime, DateTime> Parse(string line)
{
    var a = line.Split()
            .Take(2)        // take the start and end times only
            .Select(p => 
                  DateTime.ParseExact(p, "H:m",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            .ToArray();
    return Tuple.Create(a[0], a[1]);
}
```

The next stage is the algorithm itself. It has two parts. First, we find local maximums as triples of start time, end time and connection count. Second, we select the absolute maximum from the set produced by the first part:

```
File.ReadLines(FILE_PATH).Select(Parse).GetLocalMaximums().Max(x=>x.Item3)

File.ReadLines(FILE_PATH).Select(Parse).GetLocalMaximums()
    .Aggregate((x, y) => x.Item3 > y.Item3 ? x : y))

File.ReadLines(FILE_PATH).Select(Parse).GetLocalMaximums()
    .Aggregate((x, y) => x.Item3 >= y.Item3 ? x : y))
```

The most sophisticated part is detection of a local maximum.

1. Take the first period A and write down its end time. Then write down
   its start time as the last known start time. Note there is one end
   time written and there is one active connection.
2. Take the next period B and write its end time. Compare the start
   time of B to the minimum of end times written.
3. If there is no written end time smaller than B's start time then the
   number of connections increases at this time. So discard previous
   value for the last known start time and replace it with B's start
   time. Then proceed to the next period. Note again there are one more
   connections at this time and we have one more end time. So the number
   of active connections is always equal to number of written down end
   times.
4. If there is a value in the list of end time smaller than B's end, we
   had a decrease in connection count and this means we just passed a
   local maximum (here is the math). We have to report it: yield the triple (the last known start time, the minimum of written end times, the number of
   end times written minus one). We should not count the end time for B
   we had already written. Then discard all the end times being less
   than B's start time, replace the last known start time, and proceed
   to the next period.
5. When the minimum end time equals to the B's start, it means we've
   lost one connection and got another one at the same time. This means
   we have to discard the end time and proceed to the next period.
6. Repeat from step 2 for all the periods we have.

The source code for the local maximum detection

```
static IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime, int>> 
       GetLocalMaximums(this IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>> ranges)
{
    DateTime lastStart = DateTime.MinValue;
    var queue = new List<DateTime>();
    foreach (var r in ranges)
    {
        queue.Add(r.Item2);
        var t = queue.Min();
        if (t < r.Item1)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(lastStart, t, queue.Count-1);
            do
            {
                queue.Remove(t);
                t = queue.Min();
            } while (t < r.Item1);
         }

         if (t == r.Item1) queue.Remove(t);
         else lastStart = r.Item1;
    }

    // yield the last local maximum
    if (queue.Count > 0)
        yield return Tuple.Create(lastStart, queue.Min(), queue.Count);
}
```

While using [List(T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) was not the best decision, it's easy to understand. Use a sorted version of list for better performance. Replacing tuples with structs will eliminate a lot of memory allocation operations.

Comment: Does your complex solution somehow offer better results than the one I gave?

Comment: It solves completely different problem. And it is not complex.

Comment: Your simple solution does not take into account overlapping periods. You take the last int from line as number of connections while the author wrote: "Every line is a new user connection". So one line - one connection. And my solution has slightly lower memory footprint.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
string[] lines=System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
var connections = lines
    .Select(d => d.Split(' '))
    .Select(d => new 
    { 
        From = DateTime.Parse(d[0]), 
        To = DateTime.Parse(d[1]), 
        Connections = int.Parse(d[2]) 
    })
    .OrderByDescending(d=>d.Connections).ToList();
```

connections will contain the sorted list with the top results first